Wait for React context data to load before rendering consumers?
I'm using a React context in Typescript to load the user data about the user who's logged into my app (name, id, email etc.). However, when I use the useContext hook to access that data, which I'm fetching from an API, the data that comes back could be null/undefined if the hook hasn't completed  yet (understandably so). However, if I have other hooks that are dependent on user data (like looking up data with the user id), I don't want that user data to potentially be undefined. I understand that I could use an isLoading field on the context, but since I will be needing this user data on just about every screen that's a child of this context provider, I would prefer if none of the context provider's children be loaded/rendered until the user data finished, so that when I use useContext to access the user data, it must be defined. Is there a way to do this or am I not thinking about contexts in the right way?
Here is an example of the context provider:
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

const UserContext = createContext({});

export const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({});
    setTimeout(() => setUser(<something>, 1000);

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default UserContext;

And here is where I would access the context in a consumer:
const { data } = useUserDataContext()
// typeof data is any[] | undefined
// typeof data should just be any[]


Conditional rendering is typically the answer here... if (!user) return <p>Loading...</p>. FYI you context does not appear to have a data property


I would prefer if none of the context provider's children be loaded/rendered until the user data finished

Then your user provider should return null (or a loader, or something else) until it has the data, at which point it can render its children
